# Cakephp: MissingControllerException: Controller class AlarmsControllerController could not be found

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.9

I have a project on Cakephp 2.9.7. When I run test on my local machine I do not get any errors. But, when I try to run `./Console/cake test app Controller/AlarmsController` or test any other controller in my docker image, which actually has the same PHPUnit version and Cakephp version, I get an error `MissingControllerException: Controller class AlarmsControllerController could not be found.` So, the word `Controller` in the controller name is being used twice. The problem happens in https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.next/lib/Cake/TestSuite/ControllerTestCase.php#L339 this function. So the error trace looks the following way:

```
/project/lib/Cake/TestSuite/ControllerTestCase.php:347
/project/lib/Cake/TestSuite/ControllerTestCase.php:362
```

So the error causes the call of `getMock` function(https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.next/lib/Cake/TestSuite/ControllerTestCase.php#L362). But I cannot undestand what happens there, and why it works on my local machine with equal conditions(PHPUnit, Cakephp version, the same project), but in the docker container I an get error.

Comment: What if you try `./Console/cake test app Controller/Alarms` ?

Comment: @Robert, it iw not working, I get `Cannot open file "/project/app/Test/Case/Controller/AlarmsTest.php".`. The same one `./Console/cake test app Controller/AlarmsController` works on my local mashine. And the same error hapens when I try to test all the Controllers: `./Console/cake test app AllController`.

Comment: Random shot... You use Windows, Docker runs Linux and the controller file name has the wrong case?

Comment: I use  Linux, the docker image hast linux. All the versions are the same

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the controller name without the suffix Controller:

```
./Console/cake test app Controller/Alarms
```

[Docs](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html#test-case-conventions)

Comment: it iw not working, I get `Cannot open file "/project/app/Test/Case/Controller/AlarmsTest.php".`. The same one `./Console/cake test app Controller/AlarmsController` works on my local mashine. And the same error hapens when I try to test all the Controllers: `./Console/cake test app AllController`.